# Can I inherit classes as wrapper layer in CSS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Just like in programming languages! Is it possible to do something similar as shown below in CSS?

```
<style type="text/css">
   .classA { properties 1,2,3... }

   .classB { properties a, b, c... }

   .classAB { inherit- classA, classB }
</style>
```

when using Bootstrap, I often have to use lots of `div`'s which confuse me and even mess up my code. So, I decided know whether is there any feature as shown above..

Now when I apply, `<p class="classAB"></p>`, it should inherit classA and classB features!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in 'vanilla' CSS.

Use LESS or SASS, which have this functionality (and much more) and compile to CSS. See http://sass-lang.com/ or http://lesscss.org/

And of course, you could use

```
.classA { properties 1,2,3 }
.classB { properties a,b,c }

<div class='classA classB'>...</div>
```

which is not really inheritance but might do what you want.